# Visual Studio shows intellisense in XML files for abstract elements and not only for substitution groups in XSD - how to avoid this?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd

I'm developing an XSD file manly for IntelliSense in Visual Studio. Now I have a problem with substitution groups:

```
<xs:element abstract="true" name="__BuildStepTool" type="bt:BuildToolBaseType" />
<xs:element name="MSBuild" substitutionGroup="bt:__BuildStepTool" type="bt:MSBuildType">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Executes the MSBuild tool</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
```

The visual studio IntelliSense shows "__BuildStepTool" in the list of available elements at a certain point. When I use it, it allows me to insert the following:

```
<__BuildStepTool xsi:type="MSBuildType"/>
```

but I want to insert only:

```
<MSBuild Path="" Configuration="" Platform="" />
```

How can I avoid the first form in IntelliSense? The complete xsd file can be seen here:
http://download.crawler-lib.net/BuildTools/BuildConfig.xsd